# How long a temporary table and a Job goes on bigquery goes for default?

Tags: google-bigquery

By default how long a temp table will be on to get data? I know that we can set up the expiration, but what is the default? 
And about the job? What's the default expiration time if it has?

I tried to find these in the documentation but i couldn't find, we return the jobId to the client so he can get the data when the job is complete, but some of them like to store and tries to fetch data with a jobId from 2 weeks ago, 1 month  ago.

What's the default time here so i can explain them better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query results are stored for 24 hours:

> All query results, including both interactive and batch queries, are cached in temporary tables for approximately 24 hours with some exceptions.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by Alexey, they query results are stored for 24 hours when using cache.

Regarding the timelife for BigQuery jobs, you can get the job history for the last [six months](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#listing_jobs_in_a_project)

By the other side, based on your description, creating a new table from your query results with expiration time seems to be the most appropriate strategy. Also, you could check if using [materialized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views) could help you to store some results of recurring queries.